# DevOps & Development Teams Processes, Procedures, Communication & Coordination to ensure tha latest supported technologies are used in development

Tags: software-development, development-process, process-improvement, devops, technical-debt

Like many IT departments, we have numerous Developer teams, and DevOp teams.

Recently, our .NET Development Team just completed an application
based on .NET 3.1 that took around a year to complete.

We were excited to coordinate with the DevOps team in question in
order to deploy said application to the UAT environment.

Unfortunately, as we were making progress with deploying said
application, the DevOps team Management Stopped us because they said
that .NET 3.1 is No longer supported by Microsoft.
Therefore, they said that inspectors/auditors would Raise serious
concerns about having Unsupported technologies deployed to production
environment.

The politics behind said incident seemed to sort of suggest that the
DevOps team put the blame on our .NET Development Team for failing to
know that the .NET 3.1 is No longer supported by Microsoft.

As a member of the .NET Development team, I just felt like we took too
much of the blame.

What kind of  management techniques/processes/procedure could have
been put in place in order to prevent said setback incident?

Comment: Many companies use old technologies. Applications that were written a while back and nobody updated. But a new application usually implies new technologies, and apparently this was not the case here for some reason. But "implies" does not mean "must" unless the company has guidelines in place that each team must follow. Were you given such guidelines? Do these guidelines even exist? Or did someone have an "oh shit" moment and now,  all of a sudden, this is a new rule that you are guilty of not following?

Comment: Our Operations team is trying to adopt proper practices like Only using Supported 3rd-party technologies.  So, yesterday, I was annoyed as a Developer because the Operations team manager said that he would Not allow his team to deploy to UAT environment because our application was built on .NET 3.1 .  Therefore, I was hoping I could recommend some kind of practice that would have allowed us to "catch" this glaring mistake early on as opposed to finding out just before deploying to UAT.  Sorry for complaining.  :)  If you have any suggestions then please feel free to suggest.

Comment: It's fine to adopt new practices, comunicate new expectations, and ask everyone to start following them. What's not fine is if they didn't make that clear, or expecting a project that began 1 year ago to start adhering to the new practices just before deployment. This is a communication failure, a project management failure, and a governance failure. Those that make the rules need to also be the ones to make sure the rules are known. Involve your project manager and have them dueling it out with the ops manager and decide how to proceed and what to put in place so this does not happen again.

Comment: This question seems on the bubble for PMSE. It might be more appropriate on The Workplace. As written, it's an opinion poll where any answer would be hypothetical; if nothing else, the last sentence needs to be rewritten to avoid polling and allow for at least a semi-canonical project management answer. Otherwise, it will have to be closed.

Comment: Why did you cross post a question [you've already asked on DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17574/devops-development-teams-processes-procedures-communication-coordination-t)? Different Stack Exchange sites have different (but sometimes somewhat overlapping) user bases with different kinds of expertise. You should ask your question on one site where you believe that you can get the kinds of answers that would best help you.

Answer (score 5):

### Red Flags

Most of your post is out of scope insofar as it's engineering-level information and of very little practical relevance to the pragmatic controls an effective project management process would implement. Anytime you treat a project, and especially an IT project, as a fire-and-forget process without routine re-planning and refactoring, there are some nearly-universal red flags in the project initiation and implementation phases.

1. Big, upfront planning and specifications for long-term projects. *NB: This costly mistake is essentially the whole reason agile frameworks have largely displaced waterfall and other similar frameworks in most problem domains where incremental or iterative delivery is desirable, or where changing requirements are the norm.*
2. Not delivering anything until the end of a project (especially a long one) almost guarantees that it will be obsolete or unfit for purpose by the time it's delivered.
3. Failing to engage stakeholders (including your IT operations people) or customers until the end pretty much ensures that something fundamental will have changed over the course of the project, but without an inspect-and-adapt loop you won't know that until after the fact.
4. Over-engineering or (as in your case) overly-constrained dependencies that are hard to change or simply unplanned unknowns that are difficult to estimate.

Read on about what should have been done, and what the organization can do next (besides finger-pointing, of course).

### What Should Have Been Done

> What kind of management techniques/processes/procedure could have been put in place in order to prevent said setback incident?

"What kind" is easy to answer:

1. One or more formal governance frameworks to provide oversight of your project and product development process.
2. A project framework with an inspect-and-adapt cadence that's significantly faster than "yearly" or possibly "not until the end of the project."
3. A development process that continually tracks the operational environment in which it will eventually run.
4. A development process that doesn't create *excessive* coupling between the product being developed and where it will run in the future.

   *NB: This is similar to the last point, but excessive coupling is a well-known problem in software engineering where it's often a bigger problem than just the target runtime environment.*
5. Empowering the development team by "shifting left" so that the they are empowered to collaborate with QA and operations, and have the tools in place to ensure their system can be tuned for the current or future state as needed.

   *NB: Shifting left also helps teams understand what kind of lift will be required if/when the target operating environment will change, and to develop against those changes since they are not just something tossed over the wall to a separate group.*

### What the Organization Should Do Next

There's plenty of blame to go around for this type of failure, but it's surprisingly common. The overall failure rate of most IT programs is widely accepted as about 68%.

Note that your project didn't technically fail, though. You simply delivered the product as specified, maybe even on time and on budget, but since the specifications were never updated the product delivered is not currently fit-for-purpose. While that's "failure" in a business sense, it's not really a project failure; I'd call it a valuable learning experience and (possibly) a product with some misfeatures that are the fault of the *process* rather the project's sponsors, stakeholders, or developers.

Make sure you do a postmortem and fix the process issues before kicking off the next project or even fixing the current product. Unless you deal with the root cause, you will find yourself in the same position again in the future.

Comment: As a side note: I'd consider "DevOps Team" as a red flag in itself.

Answer (score 2):

Governance. Management controls. Notwithstanding the specificity of your issue, and answering this question more generally, your company lacks proper management controls over its projects. How could a project be approved with year-long spending without this issue surfacing? Your company is missing a project control point that most companies solve by using a change control board, a change architecture board, or perhaps a project steering committee where various teams and division leadership are members. Issues like what youe described would have been caught before you wasted a year's worth of expenditures.